# How to use SIGHUP for reloading services?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I've installed Hachicorp Vault and did setup the TLS configuration. My goal now is to have the `vault.service` to do an automatic reload if the TLS certificates were renewed.

The official [documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/listener/tcp#tls_cert_file)  states:

> tls_key_file (string: , reloads-on-SIGHUP) – Specifies the path to the private key for the certificate. It requires a PEM-encoded file. If the key file is encrypted, you will be prompted to enter the passphrase on server startup. The passphrase must stay the same between key files when reloading your configuration using SIGHUP. On SIGHUP, the path set here at Vault startup will be used for reloading the certificate; modifying this value while Vault is running will have no effect for SIGHUPs.

Does this mean that the service reloads itself when changes made to `tls_key_file`? or should I put additional logic?

`vault.service`

```
[Unit]
After=network.service hostname.service consul-init.service consul.service
Description="Hashicorp Vault - A tool for managing secrets"
Documentation=https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
User=vault
Group=vault
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vault server -config="{{vault_server_config_file}}"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Update**

after @Jiri B answer I re-adjusted my setup.

so now the `vault-agent.service` sends the `SIGHUP` signal to vault when the TLS certificate is renewed.

```
template {
  source      = "{{vault_template_dir}}/ca.crt.tpl"
  destination = "{{vault_tls_dir}}/ca.crt"
  command = "pkill --signal SIGHUP vault"
}
```

and `vault-agent.service`

```
[Unit]
After=network.service hostname.service
StartLimitInterval=600
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/vault-agent.pid
User=vault
Group=vault
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vault agent -config="{{vault_agent_config_file}}"
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
NoNewPrivileges=yes
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

this works fine and `vault.service` being reloaded. However, another problem emerged. Both `vault.service` and `vault-agent.service` have same user and group, and both of them should be reloaded when the certificates are renwed. It seems that the vault agent isn't coded to catch `SIGHUB` signal. So when this script runs   `command = "pkill --signal SIGHUP vault"` the `vault.service` is reloaded and running. But, the `vault-agent.service` is not able to start.

```
● vault-agent.service - "Hashicorp Vault - A tool for managing secrets"
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vault-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Tue 2021-04-06 12:17:26 UTC; 6s ago
       Docs: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
    Process: 13482 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vault agent -config=/etc/vault.d/agent.hcl (code=killed, signal=HUP)
   Main PID: 13482 (code=killed, signal=HUP)
```

any ideas regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

No, it means `vault` proces is coded in Goland in a way that it is able it catch signals, and one of the signals could be SIGHUP. When SIGHUP is catched the process will reload itself internally (ie. it won't restart it self from the scratch, it will just reload itself based on already existing arguments).

BTW, you have a typo in your code, `s/MAINIP/MAINPID`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)

See how it is done in `sshd.service`.

```
systemctl show -p ExecReload -l --no-pager sshd.service
ExecReload={ path=/bin/kill ; argv[]=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[n/a] ; stop_time=[n/a] ; pid=0 ; code=(null) ; status=0/0 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated my question, there is another problem resulted from this approach. I would appreciate very much if you have ideas on that matter.

Comment: See https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/2548414c8beb36ba5753ad0014b19a518f666696/command/agent.go#L729 What does change the TLS files on filesystem? Anyway, see `man systemd.path`, maybe it would help. IMO your `pkill` action is odd, it would match both processes. I would probably use `systemd.path` and reload server instance and restart agent instance.